# Mysql SELECT with common_schema function get_option returns NULL

Tags: mysql

So I'm trying to order items in database by value which is sum of one row json encdoded value. For example few rows looks like:

```
id | program_invested_details | program_add_status | program_status 

5  | {"invested":"120.00","received":5.4}  | 4 | 1
7  | {"invested":"120.00","received":9}    | 4 | 1
15 | {"invested":"110.00","received":50}   | 4 | 1
52 | {"invested":"110.00","received":2}    | 4 | 1
```

and my query looks like:

```
SELECT id, ((`common_schema`.`get_option`("program_invested_details", "received") * 100) / `common_schema`.`get_option`("program_invested_details", "invested")) AS PERCENT_TOTAL FROM `hp_programs_list` WHERE `program_add_status` = 4 AND `program_status` = 1 ORDER BY PERCENT_TOTAL DESC
```

but after this query result is not the same as it should be:

```
    mysql> SELECT id, ((`common_schema`.`get_option`("program_invested_details", "received") * 100) / `common_schema`.`get_option`("program_invested_details", "invested")) AS PERCENT_TOTAL FROM `hp_programs_list` WHERE `program_add_status` = 4 AND `program_status` = 1 ORDER BY PERCENT_TOTAL DESC;
+-----+---------------+
| id  | PERCENT_TOTAL |
+-----+---------------+
| 314 | NULL          |
| 308 | NULL          |
| 307 | NULL          |
| 302 | NULL          |
| 287 | NULL          |
| 285 | NULL          |
| 280 | NULL          |
| 277 | NULL          |
| 269 | NULL          |
| 319 | NULL          |
| 317 | NULL          |
+-----+---------------+
11 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

so the PERCENT_TOTAL is NULL instead of SUM. Where is the problem?

Comment: tried doing just `select get_option(...)` to see if the proper value is returned at all? I'm guessing get_option returns null on failure, which poisons everything else.

Comment: Yes, tried with only `get_option("program_invested_details", "received")` and it still returns me NULL

Comment: then you'll have to figure out why that's happening.

Comment: And yes, I'm trying to figure it put, but there is no info about it. So I'm in hope that someone has same problem too. Or had.

Comment: Try: `get_option(program_invested_details, "received")`. Remove the double quotes in column.

Comment: @wchiquito thanks, I was looking at your answer in other thread and tried to act similary. It helped a lot. Thanks. This is the proccess :) http://prntscr.com/6u80xr

Answer (score 0):

```
    mysql> SELECT `common_schema`.`get_option`(`program_invested_details`, 'received') `percent` FROM `admin_hyips_database`.`hp_programs_list` ORDER BY percent DESC LIMIT 10;
+---------+
| percent |
+---------+
| 93.50   |
| 92.13   |
| 91.47   |
| 9.90    |
| 9.19    |
| 9.14    |
| 9.13    |
| 9.02    |
| 9.00    |
| 9.00    |
+---------+
```

its working. Removed double quotes and added "`" on selector.